# Web Socket Connection- refused/failed connection in iOS Swift - Starscream/RxStarscream

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, swift4, rx-swift

I have been facing Ann issue with Websocket to connection, I have tried several methods to get connected, but always showing connection refused or failed connection. The library I have using is `Starscream` ref:- https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream and also tried with `RxStarscream` ref:- https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxStarscream.

In both cases when I tried the following code,

```
@_exported import RxSwift
@_exported import RxStarscream
import Starscream

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
 
socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/")!)
        socket.connect()

 socket.rx.response.subscribe(onNext: { (response: WebSocketEvent) in
            switch response {
            case .connected:
                print("Connected")
            case .disconnected(let error):
                print("Disconnected with optional error : \(error)")
            case .message(let msg):
                print("Message : \(msg)")
            case .data(_):
                print("Data")
            case .pong:
                print("Pong")
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I am beginner in web socket, what am trying to configure is I need to connect the websocket and socket event need to call, followed by target

```
Socket Events
URI : ws://{host}:{port}?token={_token}&lang={en}
Ip = {dev,qc}.example-app.info
Port = 8090
Main structure for Events Request and Response
{
event:”Event Name”
data:”Event Data”,
is_player:boolean(true,false)
}
Example: {"event":"xxxx","data":"xxxx", "is_player":true}
```

If anyone could give an idea or just suggestion on how to implement on the above web socket method for iOS with swift will be appreciated.

Comment: If you declare the `disposeBag` in viewDidLoad it will be deallocated as soon as the viewDidLoad execution completes. This means that your subscription will also get disposed. You should have the disposeBag as a property of the ViewController.

Comment: Just noticed that you are using `private let` in the disposeBag declaration and that should  throw a compiler error if you do that in viewDidLoad. Are you sure your copied your code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Move your  `private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()` to the outside of the `viewDidLoad`. Because the way you've done it, your subscription dies as soon as your viewDidLoad finishes executing.